# Spring Boot spring.datasource.connectionProperties not working in 1.4.1

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I was on Spring Boot 1.3.3. Upgraded to 1.4.1.

I was using

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties:stringtype=unspecified
```

in 1.3.3 because I am using PostgreSQL and have a JSONB field in my database this allows the cast from string to JSONB to work.

After upgrading to 1.4.1 this no longer works and the error is back

> ERROR: column "raw_data" is of type jsonb but expression is of type
>   character varying   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the
>   expression.

I figured out that if I do:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDatabase?stringtype=unspecified
```

That it works again without any issues. I cannot find anywhere in the spring documentation where the spring.datasource.connectionProperties was removed or replaced with something else.

What this property removed? What am I doing wrong? I would rather not put the property in my connection URL string.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to work in the first place, it worked by accident. In earlier versions all properties where bound to the underlying `DataSource` implementation, so if yours had a `setConnectionProperties` that would be bound. That binding has been disabled and as such non supported properties are ignored.

Comment: So what would be the proper solution to this then? The way i have it?

Comment: Indeed. Unless there is a specific property for the datasource implementation you use.